# Why does the Microsoft Office Custom UI XSD schema not compile using xmllint?

Tags: xml, macos, xsd-validation, xmllint, custom-ui

I've downloaded the XSD for version 2 of the Office CustomUI specification from [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui2/daabc2cd-b3f5-4d32-9099-95d705f70f35).

If I use macOS `xmllint` to validate the simple text XML doc below, using the above schema, I get a bunch of "Duplicate attribute" failures as shown in the screenshot.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
             <tab id="TabTest">
                <group id="GroupTest" label="TEST">
                    <button id="ButtonTest" label="TEST"/>
                </group>
            </tab>   
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

[image]

Microsoft's own XML 6.0 library parses the XML document against the XSD successfully.

Why doesn't it work on macOS with this command syntax from libxml?

```
xmllint --noout --schema customUI.xsd customUI.xml
```

Comment: I got same error message on Ubuntu and also with lxml from python what use libxml2, too.

Comment: Is the XML file and the version of the xsd file the same when working and not working? The filenames are at top of the error messages.  What Microsoft tools are you using?

Comment: I see the same errors reported by Xerces. Could it be that Microsoft's validator just isn't checking and reporting the duplicate attribute errors? https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#ct-props-correct `Two distinct attribute declarations in the {attribute uses} must not have identical {name}s and {target namespace}s.`

Comment: @jdweng yes. The same two files validate with the Microsoft XML 6.0 library within VBA but not with xmllint. Note that this XSD has been in use or over a decade in Microsoft Office apps. The only tools in use here are VBA and the XML 6.0 library on Windows, and the attempt to replicate the validation on macOS using VBA to call xmllint.

Comment: Interesting @MadsHansen. The suggestion that Microsoft has been using a schema across their entire Office suite since 2007, that does not adhere to W3C standards raises a wry smile. I'm going to reach out to a contact I have there to check.

Comment: The log file at top with errors indicate the schema is 2009.  Is there a newer schema?

Comment: Try validating using following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/transaction-message/validate-transaction-message  Are you getting a response status?  Here are the normal status : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/transaction-message/error-codes-messages

Comment: @jdweng the namespace hasn't changed but the schema protocol has continued to evolve, the latest release being V6 in 2021: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui2/bad56c21-7b15-41bc-af32-8b5afe6e922e

Comment: @jdweng it doesn't look like xmllint is part of a standard Windows install?

Comment: Did you see this : https://gist.github.com/cbmeeks/8317048

Comment: I did not but we tried with an up to date JRE parser and it fails there too so I've raised a ticket with Microsoft.